# Proper memory cleanup with c_str() and const char *

Tags: c++, memory-management, stdstring, const-char

I have a function that takes a (char* const*). The data I am provided is in a std::string. So I'm doing this:

```
void blahblah(std::string str)
{
   const char * cc = str.c_str();
   ConstCharFunction(&cc);
}
```

This works well. My question is do I need to clean-up the memory used by the const char ala:

```
delete cc;
```

Or is cc just a pointer to a mem location in std:string...

Comment: Why are you passing the `std::string` as a copy if you're not modifying it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a pointer to memory allocated in std::string.  When the std::string falls out of scope, the memory is released.  Be sure not to hold onto the pointer after that!

Comment: Can you give a reference that the memory will be freed?

Comment: For a reference counting pointer, you probably want something like a `shared_ptr`.  See https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers

Answer (score 2):

No you don't need to `delete cc`. It is indeed a pointer held by the `std::string` object.

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)

> A program shall not alter any of the characters in this sequence.
>
> The pointer returned points to the internal array currently used by the string object to store the characters that conform its value.

Just be careful as the pointer returned by `c_str()` may be invalidated by calling modifying methods of the string.